# Import "request" object in a views' function without pass it as argument

Tags: python, django, parameters, request, arguments

please, I need help with that "request" object that is making me despair...

I read that theoretically "request" in views is an "HttpRequest" object but I have a script which needs to call a views.py function, which needs to use that "request" so receive it as argument.

Then I tried to import that object in my script in so many modes, but it seems always **"not be the same"** and I get annoying errors as:
**"'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'session'"**

Is there another way to use "request" object in a view's function avoiding to pass as argument?
Something like this:?

```
def view_function():
    request = ??
    form = fooform
    bar = request.session['foo']
    context{
    'form' = form
    'bar' = bar
    }
    return render(request, "foo.html", context)
```

I know that's not elegant, but I'm still learning and I really don't need for this program an elegant solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if you could, **there would be no point** because your view is doing something to the session which can only exist in the context of the real request. What exactly are you trying to do with the session?

Comment: I have script.py which have a main function and an optional subfunction. Then 1: I want to   post a form and receive a text  variable with request.POST method. 2: I run the main function with Text_Variable as argument. 3: Depending of the Text_Variable, the subfunction runs, to create a form  with question and options, which need to pass to the view to show the form and get the option selected (request.POST needed). 4: The subfunction returns the option selected and the main function returns a final text_variable. The problem  is in  process number 3: i need to pass 2 variables and... Request?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand any of that. Why can't you pass the request? Or use a class-based view where the request is available throughout as `self.request`?

Comment: Thanks for  responding so fast Daniel. I can't pass request as argument because my script doesn't know what is request. Do you mean a class based view don't need request as argument?

Comment: How can it not know? If it's called when a form is submitted then it's a view, and a view gets the request as the first argument.

Comment: I called it in this way: response = main_function(Text_Variable).   I imported  the main function in views.py first but is an external script's function anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! The argument with @Daniel Roseman made me realise that I forgot to pass the "request" parameter when I call my script main funcion. That's why my external script "didn't know" what "request" was.

Thanks @Daniel Roseman for your patience!